# How to get data from ref cursor in Biztalk?

Tags: cursor, biztalk, ref-cursor

I'm using OracleDB adapter to execute a stored procedure that returns ref_cursor.
Someone knows how to get the data from the cursor?
Any examples?

Answer (score 1):

This topic is well documented at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd788392.aspx